# Removing char from string producing strange output

Tags: c, arrays, char, output, strcat

my code below is producing strange output. I'm not quite sure whats dging on. My program..this method specifically is to remove any occurrence of char c from the string.

Upon testing, if string[0] is equal to char, then that will remove the occurance. Otherwise variable: word will print the original string.

Code:

```
rmchr(char *string, char c)
{ 
  int i=0, count=0;
  char word[100]={0};

  int s = strlen(string);

  for(i=0; i<=(s-2); i++)
  {
    if(string[i] != c)
    {
      strcat(word, &string[i]);
      count++;
    }
  }
  printf("Word: ");
  for(i=0; i<=count; i++)
  {
   printf("%c", word[i]); 
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a String: Andrew
Enter a Char: f
Word: Andrew
n

Enter a String: AAABA
Enter a Char: A
Word: BA

Enter a String: David
Enter a Char: D
Word: avid
v
```

Comment: The given code cannot generate the give output. Proveide an [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

`strcat` appends a string to an existing string. So `strcat(word, &string[i]);` is **not** just appending one character, it's appending a whole string of characters to `word`.

For a better understanding of what `strcat` is doing, give this code a try

```
int main( void )
{
    char word[100] = {0};
    char string[] = "hello";
    strcat( word, &string[0] );
    strcat( word, &string[1] );
    printf( "%s\n", word );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
for(i=0; i<s; i++)
{
  if(string[i] != c)
  {
    word[count] = string[i];
    count++;
  }
}
printf("Word: ");
for(i=0; i<count; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier, better and faster to do it with pointers

```
void rmchr(char *string, char c)
{ char word[100], *p = word;
  for(; *string; string++) if(*string != c) *p++ = *string;
  *p = 0;
  printf("%s\n", word);
}
```